# Why are Klein geometries $G/H$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces

The idea behind Klein geometries is simple, clear and beautiful. Simply we have a manifold M and a Lie group G who acts on it and we study the properties that remain invariants under this action.

But then, when I open the books about Klein geometry they start with something like: choose a point $x \in M$, take the stabilizer $H$ of x, then the Klein geometry is $G/H$; instead of $(M, x)$ we can study $(G, H)$.

Now, even if I "understand" what they say, I cannot really understand what this means and why one chooses this instead of the natural definition. In particular

1. What does it really mean to study $G/H$ instead of $M$? For example if I want to study properties of curves, I will consider $\gamma: I \to M$ and not something like $\gamma: I \to G/H$. For example if I consider $M = \mathbb{R}^2$, $x = \vec O$ and $G = SO(2)$ (i.e I do not consider translations) I will have $H = SO(2)$ and $G/H = \{0\}$: what does it mean that my geometry is "empty"? What is $G/H$ in practice?
2. Why do every one define them so? Which are the advantages?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your example the action of $G$ under $x$ is trivial, and that is precisely what the quotient group $G/H$ says.

Comment: That's ok, but I cannot understand why I have to care about what happens to x! I mean: if I want to study a curve in that geometry, the action of G is not trivial!

Comment: @MarcoAll-inNervo Why would you want to study curves in this context? Generic curves $I\to M$ don't take the action of $G$ into account at all. Also note that if $G$ is compact then the orbit of $x$ is diffeomorphic to $G/H$, so the substitution makes more sense.

Comment: I think I'm missing something important. I am trying to self-study (with success, really) Cartan's method of moving frames, which, among the other things, let us study curves in arbitrary Klein geometries. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $G = SO(3)$, this reduces to the classical Frenet frame. Now we have two invariant: $\kappa (s), \tau (s)$. If two curves are $SO(3)$-equal then they have these invariants equals and if they have these invariants equals they are $SO(3)$-equal . I am asking myself what does the $G/H$ definition mean in this context.

Comment: @MarcoAll-inNervo You usually assume that the action of $G$ on $M$ is transitive. In that case $M$ is diffeomorphic to $G/H$ for some subgroup $H$. Hence $(G,H)$ fully describes $M$. But your case of $SO(3)$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not transitive (assuming standard action). So this context seems to go beyond Klein geometry. Unless you assume that each curve belongs to a single orbit?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $E(3)$, not $SO(3)$, in my last comment, but I understand that my $SO(2)$ example has the problem you say. Why we care only about transitive actions?

Comment: @MarcoAll-inNervo Precisely because if $G$ acts on $M$ transitively then $(G,H)$ fully describes this situation. If the action is non-transitive then we know that $M$ is a union of (at least two) orbits, each of which is diffeomorphic to $G/H$ ($H$ depending on orbit) but this is not enough to describe $M$. We don't know how these orbits play with each other: is it a topological disjoint union? Or something else? E.g. orbits of $SO(2)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ are just circles and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not a disjoint union of circles in topological sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Klein geometry is specified by a Lie group $G$ and a closed Lie subgroup $H < G$; sometimes we additionally require that the quotient space $X := G / H$ be connected. In particular, the action $G \times X \to X$, $g \cdot g' H := (gg')H$, is transitive.

Conversely, if we have a (perhaps connected) space $M$ admitting a transitive Lie group action $\lambda : G \times M \to M$ and we fix a point $m \in M$, the stabilizer $H$ of $m$ in $G$ is a closed subgroup and we can identify $G / H \leftrightarrow X$ via $g H = g \cdot m$. (Note that in your example, $SO(2)$ does not act transitively on $\Bbb R^2$, so this action not define a Klein geometry, at least not on $\Bbb R^2$.) Picking a different point, say, $m' = k \cdot m$ yields a conjugate stabilizer subgroup, $H' = k H k^{-1}$. In particular, the conjugation map $g \mapsto g h g^{-1}$ induces an isomorphism $(G, H) \to (G, H')$ of Klein geometries. Thus, up to this isomorphism,
$$\textbf{the data $(G, H)$ contains the same information as the data $(G, M, \lambda, x)$} .$$

There are at least two reasons to prefer working with the data $(G, H)$. One is that it is manifestly independent of the choice of basepoint $x \in M$. The second is that it emphasizes the group action of $G$ and whatever geometric structure it preserves rather than the underlying space. Indeed, sometimes a given smooth manifold is the underlying space of several different Klein geometries. For example, $S^n$ is the space underlying:

- $(O(n + 1), O(n))$: the Riemannian sphere (spherical geometry)
- $(SL(n + 1), P)$, where $P$ is the stabilizer of a ray: the projective sphere
- $(SO(n + 1, 1), P')$, where $P$' is the stabilizer of an isotropic ray: the conformal sphere
- $(Sp(2 m, \Bbb R), P'')$, $n = 2 m - 1$, where $P''$ is the stabilizer of a ray: the contact projective sphere
- $(SU(\ell + 1, 1), P''')$, $n = 2 \ell + 1$, where $P'''$ is the stabilizer of an isotropic ray: the CR sphere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, very helpful! My next question is then: why we care only about transitive actions?

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful.

As for transitivity, this is a matter of definition: The model of a Klein geometry $(G, H)$ is $G / H$, and the given action $G \times (G / H) \to G / H$ is transitive: For any element $gH \in G / H$, we have $gH = g \cdot eH$. There are many interesting situations where we have a nontransitive Lie group action on a manifold (for example, the group of isometries of a generic surface of revolution is $O(2)$), but by definition this situation is outside the scope of Klein geometry.

Comment: Thanks, really enlightening! But, for example, if I consider the Euclidean space as $M$, an arbitrary point $P\in M$ and the rigid motions as $G$, then $H=O(3)$ and it is clear to me that $M=G/H=\mathbb{R}^3$. But how can we deduce from here the gist of this geometry, that is, the Euclidean distance formula or the scalar product? Is there any method that can be translated to other Klein geometries to deduce other metrics? Thanks again for your useful answers.

Comment: @AntonioJPan That's a great question: Ultimately you're looking for whatever structure on $M$ has exactly the symmetries $G$, and for the case of Euclidean geometry we know ahead of time that the structure on $M$ is the bilinear form. (More precisely, in this case $G$ preserves and entire homothety class of bilinear forms.) Given $G, H$ it is not always easy to identify the preserved structure, though in practice usually one starts with a geometry and produces $G, H$, and not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks again. I understand. But at least, what do "they" mean with "geometric properties" of (G,H)? All the references I have found say that the pair (G,H) encodes "all the geometric properties". Obviously I undestand intuitively what a geometric property is but: is there a formal definition? Do they always refer to bilinear forms? I don't think so, because we don't have that in affine geometry or projective geometry, though they are Klein geometries.

Comment: @AntonioJPan I'm not sure that there is a general definition of "geometric structure that can be encoded with a Klein geometry" that isn't essentially tautological, formal or otherwise. You're correct that $G$ need not preserve a bilinear form on $G / H$ (and in fact it never does for the important class of Klein geometries where $G$ is semisimple and $H < G$ is a parabolic subgroup, which includes projective geometry, conformal geometry, CR geometry, and many others).

Comment: To give a flavor for how different Klein geometries can be from the Euclidean example, suppose $G=SL(3,\Bbb R)$, and let $H<G$ be the subgroup of upper triangular matrices in $G$. Then the preserved structure is a pair $(E,F)$ of line fields such that the $E \oplus F$ is a contact distribution, and the $H$-action preserves no bilinear form on $T(G/H)$, though it does preserve the bilinear map $E\times F\to T(G/H)/(E\oplus F)$ induced by the Lie bracket. (It turns out that this Klein geometry has a close relationship with the geometry of second-order o.d.e.s modulo so-called point equivalence.)